# Can we create button in Drupal 7 without writing any code?

Tags: drupal, button, drupal-7

I want to create simple HTML button which links to other page when user clicks on it. I am new to Drupal, I've seen that we can create fields from "Structure>Content Types>Article>Manage Fields>Add new field - Field types.."
Can we create button from this way or we have to write code to create it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a beta module called Button Field that works with the Rules module.  I believe will do what you're looking for.  You can add a button to any fieldable entity and define a rule for it when it's pressed.

See https://drupal.org/project/button_field and https://drupal.org/project/rules

Answer (score 1):

Buttons typically have to be coded. The way you're talking about above is the process for creating form elements for creating new pieces of content. If you want a simple button on a page to link to another page, you can just code it as follows:

```
<input type="button" value="Visit Another Page" onclick="location.href='your/other/web/page'" />
```

You may need to install a [WYSIWYG](https://drupal.org/project/WYSIWYG) text editor to add HTML to a page, if you don't already have one.

Answer (score 1):

Or just use the Field Button module: 
https://drupal.org/project/button_field

and create the buttons as you create fields...

Answer (score 0):

With the help of views or webform, block module can create a button with out writing code.